# Dialing a phone number through Bluetooth

Tags: api, mobile, bluetooth, dialing

I want to write a program under Win/Mac/*nix, that takes a phone number and dials it on my mobile through Bluetooth. I don't know much about BT. Is that possible? The mobile is mine and I WANT it to dial. How would I go about it?

Comment: I can use whatever language would work. The thing is, I want it to work on any BT phone. is that absolutely impossible/impractical?

Comment: There must be some general protocol for this. At least for calling using voice recognition - Bluetooth handsfree equipment does this, and it works for any bluetooth phone that supports this protocol. I don't know anything more....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to fetch your mobile phone manufacturer's AT command set manual. You then need to open a serial connection through Bluetooth (OS X: Connect with phone, /dev/tty.nameofyourphone should appear). You can talk with the phone as with a regular modem and send commands as specified in the documentation.